# Custom delegate not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, exc-bad-access, retain

I have started working more with delegate as suggested in another question I made. Now, I have  made a UIViewController called `ProfileViewController` in which I would like to load the News Feed from Facebook. I also have subclass of NSObject called `FBFeed`. This subclass loads the Facebook News Feed and should pass it back to the view controller. All my requests to Facebook are sent through a singleton named `FBRequestWrapper` which (in this case) should pass the result to `FBFeed`.

I call `getFBRequestWithGraphPath:andDelegate:` in `FBRequestWrapper` which will call a method in the Facebook iOS SDK which takes a delegate as a parameter. If I put in `self` (which will be the FBRequestWrapper) it works just fine. If I put in `_delegate` (which is an instance of `FBFeed`) the application crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

I have a theory why it might crash. I have read that

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id <FBFeedDelegate> delegate;
```

should be

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FBFeedDelegate> delegate;
```

But when doing so I get the following error:

> Existing ivar 'delegate' for unsafe_unretained property 'delegate'
>   must be __unsafe_unretained

Also, I don't know if that enough to make the application crash.

Here is my code.

**ProfileViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FeedTableView.h"
#import "FBFeed.h"

@interface ProfileViewController : UIViewController <FBFeedDelegate>
{
    FeedTableView *tableView;
}

- (void)loadFeed;

@end
```

**ProfileViewController.m**

```
@implementation ProfileViewController

- (void)loadFeed
{
    FBFeed *feed = [[FBFeed alloc] init];
    [feed loadNewsFeedWithDelegate:self];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma FBFeedDelegate

- (void)finishedLoadingFeed:(FBFeed *)_feed
{
    NSLog(@"ProfileViewController: FBFeed Finished.");
}

- (void)failedToLoadFeed:(FBFeed *)_feed
{
    NSLog(@"ProfileViewController: FBFeed Failed.");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load feed
    [self loadFeed];
}

@end
```

**FBFeed.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FBRequestWrapper.h"

@protocol FBFeedDelegate;

@interface FBFeed : NSObject <FBRequestDelegate>
{
    id <FBFeedDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id <FBFeedDelegate> delegate;

- (void)loadNewsFeedWithDelegate:(id)_delegate;

@end


@protocol FBFeedDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)finishedLoadingFeed:(FBFeed *)_feed;
- (void)failedToLoadFeed:(FBFeed *)_feed;
@end
```

**FBFeed.m**

```
#import "FBFeed.h"

@implementation FBFeed

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)loadNewsFeedWithDelegate:(id)_delegate
{
    self.delegate = _delegate;

    [[FBRequestWrapper defaultManager] getFBRequestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark FBRequest Delegate

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
{
    NSLog(@"FBFeed: FBRequest Did Load.");
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"FBFeed: FBRequest Failed.");
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

@end
```

**FBRequestWrapper.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface FBRequestWrapper : NSObject <FBRequestDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>
{
    Facebook *facebook;
    BOOL isLoggedIn;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isLoggedIn;

+ (id)defaultManager;
- (void)setIsLoggedIn:(BOOL)_loggedIn;
- (void)FBSessionBegin:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)_delegate;
- (void)FBLogout;
- (void)getFBRequestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)_path andDelegate:(id)_delegate;
- (void)getFBRequestWithMethodName:(NSString *)_methodName andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)_params andDelegate:(id)_delegate;

@end
```

**FBRequestWrapper.m**

```
#import "FBRequestWrapper.h"

static FBRequestWrapper *defaultWrapper = nil;

@implementation FBRequestWrapper
@synthesize isLoggedIn;

+ (id)defaultManager
{
    if(!defaultWrapper)
    {
        defaultWrapper = [[FBRequestWrapper alloc] init];
    }

    return defaultWrapper;
}

- (void)getFBRequestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)_path andDelegate:(id)_delegate
{
    if (_path != nil)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

        if (_delegate == nil)
        {
            _delegate = self;
        }

        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:_path andDelegate:_delegate];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark FBRequestDelegate

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    NSLog(@"FBRequest Failed: %@", error);
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you tell what line the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` happens in?

Comment: @Dani, I'm very bad at using the breakpoint tool but it seems that it gets pass `getFBRequestWithGraphPath:andDelegate:` and the crashes on `[self loadFeed]` in `ProfileViewController.m` (This line should be called before the `getFBRequestWithGraphPath:AndDelegate` but as mentioned, I'm bad at using the debugging tool). When the application has crashed `UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));` in `main.m` will be highlighted.

Comment: Does it sound plausible that the error mgiht be happening inside of the Facebook iOS SDK? Though, when I parse it `self` (`FBRequestWrapper`) it works fine. It's when the `FBFeed` is the delegate it crashes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you are using ARC and the new iOS5 SDK which is still under NDA. Instead of using retain, use the Keyword 'strong'. Using strong will have the same behaviour intended as using retain. Set up your property like this:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) id <FBFeedDelegate> delegate;`

Comment: Ah, of course. That made the `Existing ivar 'delegate'....` error go away but unfortunately the application still crashes.

Comment: @Suhail Patel: If anyone who pays apple $100 is able to get the "NDA" sdk, I'm not sure how much that NDA will hold and if it really means anything.

Comment: @Dani I agree but it's what you agree to when you pay your money to Apple and sign up. I think whether it'll stick is for the lawyers to decide but you won't see information and tutorials widespread until the SDK's are officially released. Until then most information will be confined in the Apple Dev Forums

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two ways for you:

1. Don't use ARC and leave your code as it was
2. If you want to use ARC, be aware that delegates normally shouldn't be retained. But when using ARC, an ivar declaration like this:

`id <FBFeedDelegate> delegate`

defaults to

```
id <FBFeedDelegate> __strong delegate
```

So when you declare a property like this:

```
@property (readwrite, unsafe_unretained) id <FBFeedDelegate> delegate
```

The ivar should look like this:

```
id <FBFeedDelegate> __unsafe_unretained delegate
```

Comment: By the way I would recommend to use ARC because it brings some great advantages like less code and therefore less errors (especially memory management errors which lead to crashes) and better performance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but then I was able to make it work correctly under iOS 5.1 on XCode 4.3.2

Use this code in your .h file

```
@protocol AnimationManagerCountdownTimerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
    -(void)countdownCompleted;

@end


@interface AnimationManager : NSObject{
....
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <AnimationManagerCountdownTimerDelegate> countdownTimerDelegate;

@end
```

Then in the .m file you simply synthesize:

```
@synthesize countdownTimerDelegate;
```