# Joystick can't hardly communicate UILabel (strong, retain, weak, etc...)

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, protocols

I'm using CPJoystick which can be found here. https://github.com/Wense/CPJoystick

I'm using Xcode 4.6 and the breakpoint stops over there.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak,   readwrite) id<CPJoystickDelegate> delegate;
```

So I made little changes. I have download hundreds of delegate and even try this one: [Custom delegate not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205064/custom-delegate-not-working)

I've tried many:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) id<CPJoystickDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<CPJoystickDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<CPJoystickDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic,assign)id delegate;
```

I don't understand what I doing. I'm stuck and confused about five weeks.

**CPJoystick.h**

```
@protocol CPJoystickDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) ShowthisNumbers:(NSString*)text;
@optional
// - (void) ShowthisNumbers:(NSString*)text;
-(void)cpJoystick:(CPJoystick *)aJoystick didUpdate:(CGPoint)movement;
@end
```

**CPJoystick.m**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     ...
     [delegate ControlPosition:@"Touched"];

}
```

I can't even make this thing communicate UILabel on  UIViewController < CPJoystickDelegate >
The joystick seems to work fine but the UILabel isn't working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    CPJoystick *joystick = [[CPJoystick alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [joystick setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"handleImage.png"] andBGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgImage.png"]];

    [joystick setMovementUpdateInterval:1.0/30];
    [self.iSneaky addSubview:joystick];
    [joystick setMoveViscosity:4 andSmallestValue:0.09]; //defaults are 7 and 0.09


}
-(void)ControlPosition:(NSString*)text;
{

    amountLabel.text = text;
}

-(void)cpJoystick:(CPJoystick *)aJoystick didUpdate:(CGPoint)movement                                
{
NSLog(@"x = %f",movement.x);
NSLog(@"y = %f",movement.y);                                                                                                    
    character.center = CGPointMake(character.center.x + movement.x, character.center.y +     movement.y);
}
```

Can anyone help me.... I need to some fresh air.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be *setting* the delgate in your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
CPJoystick *joystick = [[CPJoystick alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[joystick setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"handleImage.png"] andBGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgImage.png"]];

[joystick setMovementUpdateInterval:1.0/30];
[self.iSneaky addSubview:joystick];
[joystick setMoveViscosity:4 andSmallestValue:0.09]; //defaults are 7 and 0.09
joystick.delegate = self;
```